# Django: issues rendering form and submitting with ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I'm trying to create a form that lets users add Notes to objects. It's similiar to the django comment package but I have not been able to get that to work (the tutorial in django documentation isn't working).

Here is my model and ModelForm:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    thing_about = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        limit_choices_to={"model__in": ("Individual", "ArtsOrganization",'Presenter', "BookingAgent","Festival","ManagementCompany", "OtherOrganization","PresenterCompany", "Venue", "Gig", "Venue")},blank=True, null=True)
object_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True,)

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(('date added'), auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(('date modified'), auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.date_added)

class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
```

My views.py

```
def note(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = NoteForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = NoteForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'includes/note.html', {
    'form': form,
    })
```

I have created a template under myapp/templates/includes/note.html
so that I can use the form for each object (which all have different detail pages) i.e. make a note on the Band page and the Venue page using the same form.

Here is the contents of the template 'includes/notes.html':

```
<form action="includes/note/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is that the form does not render. I'm not sure if the view is reaching the template so that it even knows what form to render.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your `includes/note.html`?

Comment: I added the template and corrected the indents. Thanks!

Comment: what is your `urls.py` ?  Everything looks correct but I think you should make your form's action attribute use the `{% url "include_note" %}` template tag, where `include_note` refers to a named url in your `urls.py`.

Comment: What is the response from the server?

Comment: Can you paste the code in your `urls.py`?

Comment: Try to restart your server!

Comment: How are you including that template in a page? It's got its own view, which makes no sense for an include.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @CalvinCheng I didn't make a url for it because I wanted to use the include tag to add it to all of the pages that need the form. But Daniel mentioned that an include should not have a view. So now I am confused! How can I create a form that can be inserted into templates without a view? Should the form action be put into the the view of the page I want it to live on?